# Setting Background of Individual Letters (Like BBC)

Tags: html, css, properties, background, size

BBC Logo: http://www.bbc.com/ (This is the BBC page that's since been updated from the one I'm attempting to recreate; subtle differences)

My goal is to set the background of the individual BBC letters. I'm remaking the site for a course I'm taking on Udemy. I'm not having trouble in actually setting the background to white, but actually in setting the width and height of the background.

Whenever I specify the width/height in the background shorthand property there is no effect.

Sorry if I'm leaving something out here, first real post.

My current effort (sample):

HTML:

```
     <div id="logo">
       <div class="letter>
         <h1>B</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="letter>
         <h1>B</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="letter>
         <h1>C</h1>
       </div>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #7A0000; (Set text to color of page background)
  background-color: #fff; (Want to create white box around each letter)
  background-size: 25px 25px; 
}
```

Comment: Is the missing quotes on the class names just a typo copying here?

Comment: You are most certainly correct.

Answer (score 0):

background-size is to set the size of background images, not size of background-color. For set width and height possibly set the div those sizes.

```
.letter
{height:25px;
width:25px;
}
```

Comment: (Facepalm) Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, glad to help. If you're question is answered please choose an answer or post your own. Welcome to StackO.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the font size to less than 25px for the h1 if you want to set the height of .letter to 25px. You should also remove the top/bottom margins of the h1 tag, otherwise, it will come out of the box.

```
.letter h1{
    font-size:20px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mxnpf0ee/1/)